# Tor + 4G dongle

Tags: anonymity

What you want to avoid when using Tor is someone finding out the IP of your wifi network. But what if I would use a 4G dongle with a unregistered SIM-card? I would only use the 4G dongle when using Tor and I would never login to a personal account or use the 4G dongle for something personal.

Wouldn't this make me extremely hard to track? I could even use a Raspberry Pi with a SIM-card as a 4G dongle and spoof the IMEI of the Rapsberry Pi device AND connect a high gain directional antenna to the Raspberry so the 4G connects to cellular towers further away then normally.

Of course my location could still be somehow determined using triangulation but never accurate enough to actually isolate my in a crowded environment.

Answer (score 0):

well, it will make you *harder* to track, for sure - but not impossible. Your Wifi address is totally harmless to disclose: a 192.168.0.0/24 network is all around the globe, so it's not an issue at all :)